# How to differentiate under the integral sign?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I got this question while I was solving the past year papers. I read the posts about differentiation under the integral sign, but I cannot fully understand and apply them to the equation I got from the past year paper. Can anyone help me with the following equation?

$$Si(x)=\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{t}dt$$

I need to determine $Si'(x)$ and $Si''(x)$ from that. Please help with steps.

Comment: Can you take the derivative of $\int_0^x F(t)\,dt$?

Comment: This is just the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Comment: @IanColey Perhaps it's better if you explain what is $F(t)$

Comment: I was referring to the general case. The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is the appropriate route.

Comment: is it just like that Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? so if i just substitute the x into t, then it is Si'(x)??

Answer (score 2):

Since the integral exists, you know there's a primitive function $\;G\;$ s.t. (this is the FTC):

$$\int\limits_0^x\frac{\sin t}tdt=G(x)-G(0)\;,\;\;and\;\;\;G'(t)=\frac{\sin t}t\;,\;\;\text{so}$$

$$Si(x)=G(x)-G(0)\implies S_i'(x)=G'(x)=\frac{\sin x}x\;,\;\;S_i''(x)=\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}$$